# How To get All Rows in Mysql Database (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, database

So Sorry if this Looks newbie Question, Im not Skilled in Mysql, I need to Get Entries of All Rows in My Mysql Database like We Do with Sqlite in Android :

```
 Cursor mCursor = mDb.query("MyTable",new String[]{"My Column"},null,null.null,null);
 ArrayList<> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

 do{

 mylist.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

 while(mCursor.moveToNext());
```

How does This Work in Mysql Guys?

Comment: what programming language ?

Comment: try this article : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: If you need the SQL query for fetching all the rows from a database table, then the query you need to write is: `SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name`

Comment: Do you also want to know how to establish database connection and how to execute a MYSQL queryin java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you have to create connection to your database, You can use JDBC for it.

```
Connection con=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

public Dbconnection()
 {
    try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename","root","root"); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in connection"+e);
        }
}
```

connection created in the constructor,

method to get all rows from a table

```
public void getData()
{
  try{
            ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from tbl_name");

            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); //here you can get data, the '1' indicates column number based on your query

            }

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println("Error in getData"+e);
      }

}
```

In the while loop you can all data from `rs` using `rs.getString(1)` 
NB: change column number for different column.

To get more idea please refer the links:

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/
```

Comment: not toally true, but like 90% of it was, and dealed with it thanks alot